# Flutter firebase phonenumberauth how to get code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase login to let the user use Facebook, but I also need to save the phone number using otp. So I do it as follows:

```
sendOtp() async {
  print('otp call');
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: '+923323789263',
  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
  codeSent: (String verificationId, int code) {
 
  },
  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
);
}
```

OTP Code is going to the number but I need that code so I can match it with user input.

I have entered user otp to verify also like this

```
            AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                verificationId: verificationIdd,
                smsCode: textEditingController.text.trim());
            print(credential);
            FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

            final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

But i don't  want to signin I need to just check that the use enter correct otp or not. I try to print credential but its showing same response for correct and wrong otp which is this

```
AuthCredential(providerId: phone, signInMethod: phone, token: null)
```

And it's not showing anything from which i can guess otp is correct or not.

Comment: FYI, Firebase Auth doesn't provide OTP, it accepts the OTP entered by the user and sign-in the user if the OTP is correct, it only provides the OTP after verification and generating the credential. But, there's one way to pass the OTP and get the credential without signing in the user, to do that, see `_onVerificationCompleted()` of [this article](https://petercoding.com/firebase/2021/06/27/using-phone-authentication-with-firebase-in-flutter/).